# How to search mail logs effectively with `RegEx`

Tags: linux, logs, regular-expression, postfix

I was looking for some advice and examples on searching mail log effectively

Suppose situation is like this

```
-------- Forwarded Message --------
Subject: Fwd: Re: Notice of Allowance 
Date: Fri, 13 Mar 2015 16:02:17 +0530
From: Sachin Tendulkar <sachin@tendulkar.glbl>
To: Brett lee <brett@lee.glbl>
CC: 'Brian Lara' <brian@lara.glbl>
```

Now Problem is mail not received by recipient so I have to find out what's wrong and I can do that by `grepping`.

What I did is `grep "from=<sachin@tendulkar.glbl>" /var/log/mail.log` then again grepped the queue ids.

My question is: what would be most effective `syntax` to search for the exact mail or narrow down the search result as the command I used returned 83 results!

PS: Any link to some good materials on `Searching Logs` will also be very helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by "search for the exact mail"? - If the recipient complains that the mail did not arrive, search for mails matching `^To: .*<recipient-address>`. And if the sender complains, search for mails matching `^From: .*<sender-address>`.

Comment: @janis, Thanks for your prompt reply.
I exactly did that and the again grepped the queue id in the mail log but in between 16:00 to 16:15 83 mails has been sent so I was wondering is there any way to search option can be more precise.

since the mail had 3 recipients so was it possible to narrow down the search somehow?

Comment: Really wondering whats the negative vote for?  Is it a fashion here? Or only masters with huge rep can ask questions?

Comment: I'm wondering myself as well. The reason may be that your question is not formulated clear enough. Though personally I don't think it's worth a downvote. IMO, a comment is more appropriate to give the poster a chance to edit his question.

Comment: WRT your question in the other comment; it's still not clear enough what exactly you want. Maybe you can extend your question appropriately and supported by samples. Comment fields are not well suited for descriptions or non-trivial clarifications of the actual question.

Comment: What I did is `grep "from=<sachin@tendulkar.glbl>" /var/log/mail.log` and there were 83 mails. I just want to narrow down the search by using something like 
`grep "from=<sachin@tendulkar.glbl>" /var/log/mail.log | grep nrcpt=3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the idea from this thread on SF:  [Need help grepping postfix log](https://serverfault.com/questions/623892/need-help-grepping-postfix-log).

First you should search all possible queue IDS matching your criteria. To do that you can use command

```
grep 'from=<sachin@tendulkar.glbl>' /var/log/maillog | cut -d ' ' -f 6
```

or

```
grep 'to=<recipient@example.com' /var/log/maillog | cut -d ' ' -f 6
```

Then you can use queue ID from the log to list all information based on queue ID

```
grep 'to=<sachin@tendulkar.glbl>' /var/log/maillog | cut -d ' ' -f 6 | grep -f - /var/log/maillog
```

Of course that will list all entry, if you need `grep nrcpt=3` then pipe them.

```
grep 'to=<recipient@example.com' /var/log/maillog | cut -d ' ' -f 6 | grep -f - /var/log/maillog | grep nrcpt=3
```

*Additional note:*

The above email above only list **address in email header**. But, postfix only **logs the envelope address**.